# illustrator: Aligning an object to the top of an angled shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, illustrator-scripting

I want to align an object to the top of a shape with an angled side. like so:[image: Desired result]

Let's say this is my starting position of the object I want to move:

[image: starting point]

If I select both and do 'vertical align top'. It's obviously going to align the object with the highest point of the shape it can find. like so: [image: Vertical align top]

Is there a way for the object to align with the top side of the shape?
It can't be a manual solution as I'm trying to figure this out for a script I'm writing.

Thank you.

Comment: I can think of a couple of semi-automatic ways to do this involving snapping to point and Smart Guides. Would those work for you?  If so I can add an answer.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think he'll need the coordinates of slope.

Comment: Don't think this can be automated, at least not easily. You'd need to detect the pixel at the top where overlap stops.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure *View > Smart Guides* is enabled.
2. Using the Line Segment tool `\`, move your mouse over the top-left corner of the square until the word *anchor* appears, then click and drag up to the angled top side of the other shape, hold `Shift` to make the line straight, and let go when you see *intersect* appear. Now you have a line whose length is the exact distance that you need to move the blue square.
3. Check the length of the line in the Transform panel and make a note of it or copy it to clipboard.
4. Switch to Selection tool `V` and select the blue square, then press `Enter` to open the Move dialog. Paste the value you copied/noted but add a hyphen to make it negative (to move up instead of down), then press OK.

Now the top left corner of the square is perfectly aligned with the angled top edge of the other shape.